# BroadcastProcessFunction Processing Delay

Tags: apache-flink

I'm fairly new to Flink and would be grateful for any advice with this issue.

I wrote a job that receives some input events and compares them with some rules before forwarding them on to kafka topics based on whatever rules match. I implemented this using a flatMap and found it worked well, with one downside: I was loading the rules just once, during application startup, by calling an API from my main() method, and passing the result of this API call into the flatMap function. This worked, but it means that if there are any changes to the rules I have to restart the application, so I wanted to improve it.

I found [this page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/fault-tolerance/broadcast_state/) in the documentation which seems to be an appropriate solution to the problem. I wrote a custom source to poll my Rules API every few minutes, and then used a BroadcastProcessFunction, with the Rules added to to the broadcast state using processBroadcastElement and the events processed by processElement.

The solution is working, but with one problem. My first approach using a FlatMap would process the events almost instantly. Now that I changed to a BroadcastProcessFunction each event takes 60 seconds to process,  and it seems to be more or less exactly 60 seconds every time with almost no variation. I made no changes to the rule matching logic itself.

I've had a look through the documentation and I can't seem to find a reason for this, so I'd appreciate if anyone more experienced in flink could offer a suggestion as to what might cause this delay.

The job:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // set up the streaming execution environment
    final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.IngestionTime);

    // read the input from Kafka
    DataStream<KafkaEvent> documentStream = env.addSource(
        createKafkaSource(getSourceTopic(), getSourceProperties())).name("Kafka[" + getSourceTopic() + "]");

    // Configure the Rules data stream
    DataStream<RulesEvent> ruleStream = env.addSource(
    new RulesApiHttpSource(
        getApiRulesSubdomain(),
        getApiBearerToken(),
        DataType.DataTypeName.LOGS,
        getRulesApiCacheDuration()) // Currently set to 120000
    );

    MapStateDescriptor<String, RulesEvent> ruleStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<>(
        "RulesBroadcastState",
        BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
        TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<RulesEvent>() {
        }));

    // broadcast the rules and create the broadcast state
    BroadcastStream<RulesEvent> ruleBroadcastStream = ruleStream
        .broadcast(ruleStateDescriptor);


    // extract the resources and attributes
    documentStream
        .connect(ruleBroadcastStream)
        .process(new FanOutLogsRuleMapper()).name("FanOut Stream")
        .addSink(createKafkaSink(getDestinationProperties()))
        .name("FanOut Sink");

    // run the job
    env.execute(FanOutJob.class.getName());
}
```

The custom HTTP source which gets the rules

```
public class RulesApiHttpSource extends RichSourceFunction<RulesEvent> {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RulesApiHttpSource.class);

private final long pollIntervalMillis;
private final String endpoint;
private final String bearerToken;
private final DataType.DataTypeName dataType;
private final RulesApiCaller caller;
private volatile boolean running = true;


public RulesApiHttpSource(String endpoint, String bearerToken, DataType.DataTypeName dataType, long pollIntervalMillis) {
    this.pollIntervalMillis = pollIntervalMillis;
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    this.bearerToken = bearerToken;
    this.dataType = dataType;
    this.caller = new RulesApiCaller(this.endpoint, this.bearerToken);
}


@Override
public void open(Configuration configuration) throws Exception {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    // do nothing
}

@Override
public void run(SourceContext<RulesEvent> ctx) throws IOException {

    while (running) {
        if (pollIntervalMillis > 0) {
            try {
                RulesEvent event = new RulesEvent();
                event.setRules(getCurrentRulesList());
                event.setDataType(this.dataType);
                event.setRetrievedAt(Instant.now());

                ctx.collect(event);
                Thread.sleep(pollIntervalMillis);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                running = false;
            }
        } else if (pollIntervalMillis <= 0) {
            cancel();
        }
    }
}

public List<Rule> getCurrentRulesList() throws IOException {
    // call API and get rulles
}


@Override
public void cancel() {
    running = false;
}
```

}

The BroadcastProcessFunction

```
public abstract class FanOutRuleMapper extends BroadcastProcessFunction<KafkaEvent, RulesEvent, KafkaEvent> {

protected final String RULES_EVENT_NAME = "rulesEvent";
protected final MapStateDescriptor<String, RulesEvent> ruleStateDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<>(
    "RulesBroadcastState",
    BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO,
    TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<RulesEvent>() {
    }));

@Override
    public void processBroadcastElement(RulesEvent rulesEvent, BroadcastProcessFunction<KafkaEvent, RulesEvent, KafkaEvent>.Context ctx, Collector<KafkaEvent> out) throws Exception {
        ctx.getBroadcastState(ruleStateDescriptor).put(RULES_EVENT_NAME, rulesEvent);
        LOGGER.debug("Added to broadcast state {}", rulesEvent.toString());
    }

// omitted rules matching logic
```

}

```
public class FanOutLogsRuleMapper extends FanOutRuleMapper {

public FanOutLogsJobRuleMapper() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void processElement(KafkaEvent in, BroadcastProcessFunction<KafkaEvent, RulesEvent, KafkaEvent>.ReadOnlyContext ctx, Collector<KafkaEvent> out) throws Exception {
    RulesEvent rulesEvent = ctx.getBroadcastState(ruleStateDescriptor).get(RULES_EVENT_NAME);

    ExportLogsServiceRequest otlpLog = extractOtlpMessageFromJsonPayload(in);

    for (Rule rule : rulesEvent.getRules()) {
        boolean match = false;
        // omitted rules matching logic

        if (match) {
            for (RuleDestination ruleDestination : rule.getRulesDestinations()) {
                out.collect(fillInTheEvent(in, rule, ruleDestination, otlpLog));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can give the complete code of the FanOutLogsRuleMapper class, currently the match variable is always false